# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types | Erro PHP

Tags: php

Dentro deste Script, dá o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in
>   C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\Administrar\application\views\holerites\holerites.php
>   on line 126

```
        if($r->totalProvento==NULL){
            #total a receber
            $totalProvento = "0.00";
            $totalDesconto = "0.00";
            $totalReceber = "0.00";
        } else { 
            #total a receber
            ----> 126 - $totalProvento = $r->totalProvento->totalProvento + $r->salario;
            $totalDesconto = $r->totalDesconto->totalDesconto;
            $totalReceber = $totalProvento - $totalDesconto;
        }
```

Comment: Algum deles é vazio?

Comment: Sim, pode ocorrer do array vir vazio

Comment: faz um cast para double, ele deve forçar o null ou '' para zero

Comment: _Strings_ não são _números_, e _números_ não são _strings_, foi exatamente isso que você fez aí, colocando os `0.00` entre `" "`

Comment: Nao entendi nada..

Comment: O que é isto ? `$r->totalProvento->totalProvento` ?

Comment: Está certo isso ----> 126 ?

Comment: Só estou indicando a qual linha que esta vindo erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo seu if errado, pois se entrar na primeira condição, não vai entrar no else que é onde ocorre a soma a te retorna o erro de tipagem.

Tenta isso:

```
$totalProvento = ($r->totalProvento==NULL ? 0.00 : ($r->totalProvento->totalProvento + $r->salario));
$totalDesconto = ($r->totalProvento==NULL ? 0.00 : $r->totalDesconto->totalDesconto);
$totalReceber = ($r->totalProvento==NULL ? 0.00 : ($totalProvento - $totalDesconto));

// ou

if($r->totalProvento==NULL){
    #total a receber
    $totalProvento = 0.00;
    $totalDesconto = 0.00;
    $totalReceber = 0.00;
}

$totalProvento = ($r->totalProvento->totalProvento + $r->salario);
$totalDesconto = $r->totalDesconto->totalDesconto;
$totalReceber = ($totalProvento - $totalDesconto);
```